# Troubleshooting creating a function to swap elements in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble understanding the for loop needed to create a function that swaps elements in a Python list.

I am trying to create the function using one for loop but apparently more than one is required

Inputs:

```
n = int(input().strip())
a = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
```

My method:

```
def count_swaps(a):
    total_swaps = 0
    i = 0 
    if a[i + 1] > a[i]:
        total_swaps += 1   
        temp = a[i+1]
        a[i+1] = a[i]
        a[i] = temp
    return total_swaps
```

Correct solution:

```
def count_swaps(a):
    total_swaps = 0

    for i in range(n):
        swaps = 0
        for j in range(n-1):
            if a[j] > a[j+1]:
                temp = a[j+1]
                a[j+1] = a[j]
                a[j] = temp
                swaps += 1           
    total_swaps += swaps

    return total_swaps
```

My question is, why is there need of two for loops, i.e. the `j in range(n-1)` and `i in range(n)`? In addition, should the range not be the same in both?

Comment: It appears you are doing a bubble sort to count the number of inversions in an array. This means `total_swaps` is the number of all pairs in the array such that `A[i] > A[j]` and `i < j`. Your function only counts the number of swaps necessary between adjacent elements, while the correct answer counts the total number of swaps needed to make the array sorted.

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding ( I am a beginner at this) but I am not sure how the number of swaps between adjacent elements don't equal the total number of swaps needed. I am having trouble understanding what the `j` denotes here and `a[i] > a[i +1] ` is not sufficient

Comment: Say `a = [9, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. The number of adjacent swaps you calculate is `1`. However the total number of swaps is needed is `4`, you have to swap `9` with each `1` and let it move up in the array.

Comment: Thankyou so much I understand now !